# Create gradle sample project for eclipse (java web)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, gradle

I use gradle for some time and I want to create my own sample projects for eclipse like those IDE already contains 'Java Quickstart', 'flat-java-multiproject'. Is it possible to do it? If yes, how can I do it? WHy I want to do it? Because it is annoying to create new project manually everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in I solved this problem in this way http://github.com/pepuch/gradleTemplatesCreator. Project was created for my own usage so it's not clear and finished.